# psycopg2 - Use wildcard for select statement with sql composition?

Tags: psycopg2

Is it possible to use SQL composition to accommodate a dynamic 'SELECT *' statement with psycopg2? This is against a Postgres 11.6 database.

My code executes from shell, and using argparse the user can provide a column name as `q_col_list` to return from a SELECT query. If they do not specify `q_col_list` the default is set to '*'.

Is it necessary and possible to utilize SQL composition to accommodate a 'SELECT *' statement?

For now I have a simple if statement that checks the value of `q_col_list`. If `q_col_list` is specified as '*' it runs one query with 'SELECT *' manually defined. Else it runs a different query expressing the variable `q_col_list`. This is shown in the snippet below:

```
  if q_col_list == '*':
      cursor_query = sql.SQL("""SELECT * from {q_tab_name} WHERE {q_where_col} LIKE {q_wherel_str}""").format(
      q_tab_name=sql.Identifier(q_tab_name),
      q_where_col=sql.Identifier(q_where_col),
      q_wherel_str=sql.Literal(q_wherel_str),
    )
  else:
    cursor_query = sql.SQL("""SELECT {q_col_list} from {q_tab_name} WHERE {q_where_col} LIKE {q_wherel_str}""").format(
    q_col_list = sql.Identifier(q_col_list),
    q_tab_name = sql.Identifier(q_tab_name),
    q_where_col = sql.Identifier(q_where_col),
    q_wherel_str = sql.Literal(q_wherel_str),
  )
  cursor.execute(cursor_query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query should work using `q_col_list = sql.SQL("*")` as a parameter.